# PyAutoGUI locate command returning incorrect coordinates for image recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen, bots, pyautogui

I am trying to use `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()` to find the exact point of an image on a screen, but whenever the coordinates are returned it seems to always be larger by a factor of two (i.e. gives `(2026, 722)` but actually is `(1013, 361)`). I am using a Macbook Pro 2016 with Retina Display running macOS Sierra. Any suggestions how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

[Image Recognition Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDIAl.png)

[Image to locate on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGJsy.png)

I hope this screenshot will help with solving my problem.

Answer (score 13):

```
import pyautogui
position = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('image.png')
print(position.x/2,position.y/2)
pyautogui.click(position.x/2,position.y/2)
```

Comment: It helps if you give a bit of explanation why this is a a solution

Answer (score 7):

Pyautogui uses screencaps to find the location of stuff on the screen. The problem on macs with a retina display is that the screen output have double the number of pixels, to take advantage of the system’s greater pixel density for a crisper image.Therefore, when you take a screenshot, you get an image containing double the number of pixels than the same image from a non-retina Mac. I'm currently looking into whether it is possible to resize the image and still be able to find a match (one pixel off and theres no match if not using cv2's fuzzy search)
[source](http://www.macissues.com/2014/03/29/adjust-retina-macbook-screenshots-to-be-actual-size/)

Comment: For some reason it works really good however there are some cases in which the thing does not work. May you help? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason my m1 Macbook didn't like these answers so here is what I came up with.

```
position2 = position[0]/2, position[1]/2, position[2]/2, position[3]/2
pyautogui.moveTo(position2)
pyautogui.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is not a problem you can fix by looking at the code or the module you are using. Most probably the problem is that YOU interpret something the wrong way.

If you provide the screenshot and the image you want to locate on it, it would be much easier to help without the need for guessing.

Comment: Hi, I have edited and added screenshots. Hopefully this can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also with MacBook. I can only think it has to do with the MacBook and the way it is sending screen information.

As a work around I have just been dividing the coordinates by 2.